# Can't run Kivy on Ubuntu Wily

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy

I'm new to python and kivy and I want to run my first kivy program. When I run the program I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/mmu/PycharmProjects/ShipControl/gui/gui.py
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/mmu/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-11-29_0.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 65, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 616, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 171, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 60, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1379)

x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've installed kivy using

```
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

Am I missing something? When I search for these errors I've found people suggesting installing pygame but that seems to be a dead project?

Comment: I think this is a known issue, but I'm not sure what the status of it is. Have oyu tried using kivy's master branch (the daily package)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inclement said in his comment switching to kivy-daily resolved the problem! I had to do a dist-upgrade on my machine to resolve some dependencies.

Comment: Could you eloborate a bit more on this solution? How do you switch to the kivy-daily?

Answer (score 3):

This problem also occurred on 16.04 for me.

My solution, removing the ubuntu package (to be on the save side) and install with pip:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-kivy
sudo pip3 install kivy
```

Answer (score 2):

I just installed kivy on wily from git, this is my bash_history

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir ~/code
cd ~/code
git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy
cd kivy/
wget http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
pip install cython --user
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev
pip install cython --user
sudo apt-get install libgles1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev     libsdl2-image-dev     libsdl2-mixer-dev     libsdl2-ttf-dev     libportmidi-dev     libswscale-dev     libavformat-dev     libavcodec-dev     zlib1g-dev
make
export PYTHONPATH=~/code/kivy/
pip install pygments --user
pip install docutils --user
python examples/demo/showcase/main.py
```

For using python3 just replace `make` with `python3 build_ext --inplace` pip with pip3 and then you can run using python3

Answer (score 1):

My solution was similar to Sebastian's, but applies to Python 2.7.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-kivy
sudo pip install kivy
sudo pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by mistakе `sdl2` - `TypeError: expected bytes, str found`

the installation of the `sdl2 dependency` helped me:
`sudo apt-get install python3-sdl2`

Answer (score 0):

I have installed every package pointed here... what fixed for me was exporting the display (I was connecting through VNC on a Orange Pi)

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```